# Some misunderstanding in ChangeType method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a newer in c# so maybe my question will seem naive to some of you.

I'm using this method:

```
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType);
```

From metadata manual:

> Returns:
>
> > An object whose type is conversionType and whose value is equivalent
> >     to value.-or-A
> >                  null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), if value is null and conversionType
> >                  is not a value type.

But in method signature the returned type always 'object'. So, what is the benefit in converting the value if returned type is `object`?

Comment: it should return the object with Type you have specified in conversionType do you just need to cast the result from object to the type you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you can cast to your particular type. This method comes from before generic types so the only way it could return one of any number of types is by returning the supertype of all of them, ie object. You can of course then cast that to your chosen type and guarantee you will be successful but the only other option would be an overload of every single type ever which would be a bit weighty. :)

The thing to note is that this isn't just the same as casting. It will return a whole new object which is the type you asked for rather than the type you gave it.

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ChangeType` creates a new object of the specified type, with a value equivalent to the object you passed.

For example, `Convert.ChangeType("42", typeof(int))` will return a boxed `int` instance rather than a string.

The actual behavior is completely within the `IConvertible` implementation of the object you pass.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

from the msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa324833(v=vs.71).aspx

*

> value
>  An Object that implements the IConvertible interface.

*

Answer (score 1):

In .net methods have a fixed signature (with generics you can go further, but that's not the case here) - so for this conversion method they chose the most common type: `object`.

Consider `Person` and `Man`. `Man` is defined as

```
class Man : Person
```

In order to create an address book, you would not create two methods:

```
Man GetByName(string name);
Woman GetByName(string name);
```

Instead you would create one method:

```
Person GetByName(string name);
```

This method would return a `Person` and even though the actual object returned is a `Man`, all you currently know about it is that it's a `Person`.

Back to the converter: *you* know the return type as you supplied it in the parameters, but a long time ago when the method was created they did not know what you were going to supply as parameter. You can safely cast the result to the type you already know:

```
MyType myObject = (MyType)ChangeType(value, typeof(MyType));
```